# How does one evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n] {2^n+3^n+\sin n} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

> How does one evaluate 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n] {2^n+3^n+\sin n} \ \ ?
> $$

I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: The $\sin$ term is completely negligible and $3^n>>2^n$ for large $n$.

Comment: What similar examples of limits have you seen?

Comment: Hint: As $n \to \infty$ $$3^n >>2^n>>>> \sin n $$.so your question is nothing but $(3^n)^{1 \over n}=3$

Comment: @Rishi I've added some more information since sometimes this rough estimation can lead to errors.

Comment: @gimusi  i know it's a handle with care method . But there we can simply  observe , $9>4$ ,  $27>8$ , $81>16$ How rapidly the gap increasing.

Comment: To come back to "How does one evaluate", well... Always the same method **factor out the major term**, here $3^n$.

Comment: @Rishi I agree and it is the key point! My advice is about the $n^{th}$ root. It is important to be aware that we can conclude that $a_n \to 1 \implies \sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 1$. For beginners, this point can lead to errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT**

We can use that

$$\sqrt[n] {2^n+3^n+\sin n}=3\cdot \sqrt[n] {\left(\frac23\right)^n+1+\frac {\sin n} {3^n}}$$

and also recall that

- $a_n \to 1 \implies \sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 1$

indeed

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=e^{\frac{\log a_n}{n}}\to e^0=1$$

Answer (score 6):

A possible way is also squeezing:

For $n \geq 1$ you have
$$3 =\sqrt[n] {3^n}\leq \sqrt[n] {2^n+3^n+\sin n} \leq \sqrt[n] {3\cdot 3^n} = 3 \underbrace{\sqrt[n] {3}}_{\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}1}$$

Comment: Nice alternative!

Comment: @gimusi ... thanks .. and welcome back ... haven't seen you around for quite a while.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to see you again!